# Associated PXSelect/PXSelectReadOnly Returns Nothing on Sales Order Through OpenAPI

Tags: acumatica

I've introduced a new DAC and a new field on the Sales Order associated to the new DAC key. When trying to retrieve the information through OpenAPI it comes back empty. I'd like to know why and how I can adjust my code to return the information. I've tried both PXSelect and PXSelectReadOnly

Declaring Statement on SOOrderEntry(extension):

```
public PXSelect<IOCSCompanyBrand, Where<IOCSCompanyBrand.companyBrandNbr, 
        Equal<Current<SOOrderExt.usrCompanyBrand>>>> CompanyBranding;
```

[image: Sales Order with Information Shown]

When I hit the URL: http://localhost/Acumatica21/entity/AcumaticaExtended21R1/20.200.001/SalesOrder?$select=OrderNbr,CompanyBranding,OrderType,CompanyBrand&$expand=CompanyBranding&$filter=OrderNbr%20eq%20'SO-030003'

This is the data that is returned:

```
[
{
    "id": "f827cb43-9b8a-ec11-a481-747827c044c8",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "CompanyBrand": {
        "value": "IO"
    },
    "CompanyBranding": null,
    "OrderNbr": {
        "value": "SO-030003"
    },
    "OrderType": {
        "value": "SO"
    },
    "custom": {}
}
]
```

Acumatica Version: 21.205.0063

Here's the definition for SalesOrder in the endpoint (which was populated via the GUI)[image]

Comment: Can you share with us your API Definition for AcumaticaExtended21R1 for the sales order entity ?

Comment: Absolutely! I've added it to the body of the question.

Comment: As a side note, I'm having to adjust the endpoint name to prevent company name from being shared. It's the right endpoint being hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a Acumatica Developer case and here is their response.

Hi Kyle,

Thanks for your time yesterday.

Endpoint mapping is valid but the fields in the view isn't fetch due the limitation of the filter parameter in the request. Filter parameter optimizes the data that are being fetch. In the case, the customer view isn't fetched. To workaround the limitation, instead of using filter, you can try something like below,

http://localhost/Acumatica/entity/AcumaticaExtended21R1/20.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/SO-030007?$expand=CompanyBranding

You can fetch the record and use expand to get the detail level fields. This way you can avoid the limitation of the filter.

Please check and let me know if you have any questions.

Regards,
Vignesh